WPF Binding DataGrid Template Column ComboBox CellEditingTemplate and Text CellTemplate
I have a collection of Products { SuppliesId, SupplierProductName }
I also have an invoice which connects to this product list ProductInvoice {InvoiceId, SupplierProductId }
I have created a WPF DataGrid with a combobox which is bound to the {SupplierProductName} for display and the {SupplierProductId} and this all works fine in displaying the {SupplierProductId} but I would like it to display the {SupplierProductName}
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Product">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SupplierProductId}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.AllSupplierProducts, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SupplierProductId, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="SupplierProductName"
                  SelectedValuePath="SuppliesId" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

